# ASP.net Connecting to two databases at once?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, multiple-databases

Is connecting to two SQL databases at the same time possible ? I mean from one database I am reading records and comparing them with some data like email address and based on the decision that whether that email address exists in the database or not I am storing a new record in another database.

Is this kind of double operation possible ?

I am connecting with databases using SqlConnection and SqlCommand statements of C#.net

Thank you.

Comment: Did you face any issue when you tried?

Comment: Of course is possible: use two connection object. Do you face any trouble?

Comment: No I haven't tried it, I was googling about it before trying and found that it is considered as bad design/practice but didn't found why exactly so I thought I should ask here. Actually the databases I am using are two entirely different databases but the table of clients (in first database) is also needed by the second database to check existing email addresses. Also I am performing a very critical operation based on the decision of new or existing email because it will decide whether an email is about sales department or support department so if this approach has any issues then I drop it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

You can either return a value to your asp.net application, and then connect to another database like:

```
cmdEmailExists SqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SQL HERE...", Conn1);

if (((int)cmdEmailExists.ExecuteScalar())>0){
   cmdInsert SqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SQL INSERT HERE...", Conn2)
   cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Where `Conn1` and `Conn2` are 2 different `SqlConnection`'s connecting to 2 different databases.

Or this can be done at SQL end like:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT Email FROM [Database1].dbo.tbl)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO [Database2].dbo.tbl ..........
END
```

Answer (score 1):

may be this helps you
or post ur code

```
 SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con1"].ConnectionString);
    SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con2"].ConnectionString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from table1", con1);
    SqlDataReader dr;
    con1.Open();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult);
    while (dr.Read())
    { 
  //  ....
    }dr.Close()

   //your condition then fire insert commnd with connection con2 

    SqlCommand insertcmd = new SqlCommand("insert into table2", con2);
    SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(insertcmd);
```

//     ...

Answer (score 1):

This is nice solution but not the correct answer! There is no need of using 2 connection string in order to use 2 different databases on the same server (as long as the user have the right permission). We specify the Initial Catalog during the connection, to define where we want to run the query, but if the user have enough permissions to execute the query on other databases, he can do that **using the two dots Db..table notation**!

This code will work using one connection string!

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Use-connection-string-here");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
"select * from Table1 t1 left join Database2..Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id", con
);
```